# Find probability that at least one of the two cards is a face card using Event composition when 2 cards are drawn randomly, no replacement

Tags: probability

If two cards are drawn at random without replacement from a standard deck, find the probability that at least 1 card is a face up.

With sample point method, I got ${12 \choose 1}$ ${40\choose 1}$ +${12 \choose 2}$ ${40 \choose 0}$ divided by ${52 \choose 2}$, getting 53/663 but when i do event composition, I got 7/17 from doing 1-(40/52 * 34/51).

I am not sure what I am doing wrong because aren' they suppose to be the same?

Comment: You may have calculation mistake. Both give the same value.

Comment: @MathLover oh? my equation for both is correct?

Comment: Yes both equations are correct. You have written $34$ by mistake in the second instead of $39$ but you have got the correct answer of $7/17$.

Comment: @MathLover MathieuRund  ahh i see it..thanks for taking a look at it! Lowkey was losing my confidence in this ;—;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is $\frac{7}{17}$. I think you made a computational mistake in your first calculation.

Comment: I am not sure why someone downvoted it. May be because you just wrote a line. Better to add equations and details to your answer.

Comment: @MathLover I am unsure as well. I didn't feel the need to add any details as op had included all details needed, modulo the typo you pointed out.

Comment: @MathieuRund Not sure who downvoted you, but for sure i found my mistake. Thanks for looking at it :)